# MongoDB QueryBuilder method with runtime variable

Tags: mongodb, query-builder

I'm trying to create a function that returns BasicDBObject "queryDB" as:

```
public static DBObject buildQuery(String lang) {
        QueryBuilder query = new QueryBuilder();
        query.put("key").lessThanEquals("value1");
        query.and("field1").equals(lang);
        DBObject queryDB= new BasicDBObject();
        queryDB.putAll(query.get());
        return queryDB;
    }
```

which gives me the following:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.mongodb.QueryBuilder$QueryBuilderException: No operand for key:field1
at somepackage.QueryBuilder.get(QueryBuilder.java:442)
at somepackage.MongoClass.buildQuery(MongoClass.java:72)
at somepackage.MongoClass.getDocsOf(MongoClass.java:44)
at somepackage.App.main(App.java:39)
```

Any ideas to prevent or fix that?

Answer (score 0):

In your `and` clause, you're calling `equals()` which is the `Object.equals()` method and not a query operator.  Try changing that `equals()` to `is()`.  That worked for me when I updated your code.

Comment: unfortunately that didn't work, when i get 'lang' documents from the terminal i get a count of 25000, from the java code, i only get 1659 for some reason